# Asana API - get all conversations of team

Tags: asana, asana-api

Asana's API looks great, but I tried to get all conversations per team and I didn't find way to do this.

Is there a best solution to get conversations from Asana? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find some workaround to get conversations via API, but we need to know all conversation IDs. So:

Go to your team page -> team conversations -> click on any conversation and take a look on URL string, pattern will be like this: 
`https://app.asana.com/0/TeamID/ConversationID`

Copy ConversationID from URL and past it in following link: `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/ConversationID/stories?opt_pretty`

Profit! You can see your conversation in JSON :)

All you need - get\parse all conversation ID. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Team and project conversations has not yet been released in the API. It is on our roadmap to be released with no specific date set.

Please [subscribe to our API newsletter](https://asana.com/developers/subscribe) in order to stay up to date with the latest feature releases.

Comment: Thanks! As temporary workaround i find specific way: move all conversations to projects :)